# xVid. Проблемы с битрейтом

Tags: c#, windows, видео, кодек

Проблемка заключается в следующем. Настраиваю конфиг xVid так, чтобы битрейт был либо очень маленьким, либо очень большим. Пробовал на разных видео. Но у всех одна и та же беда. В зажатом видео битрейт очень и очень сильно отличается от того, что мне нужно получить. Под час он становится почему-то даже больше, чем у исходного.

Пробовал по-разному:

- ставить абсолютное значение размера изображения;
- выставлять размер битрейта;
- ёрзать слайдером;
- выставлять значения битрейта в пределах допустимого и за его пределами.

Ничего не помогает.

[image: Конифиг битрейта]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одно из возможных решений -- это использовать графический пользовательский интерфейс. Там баги пропадают.